# Git: Object in Version Control cannot be removed

Tags: git

I am trying to push my local branch to my origin branch with `git push origin <branchname>`. 
I get a:

```
remote: error: File app/assets/images/title00.mp4 is 297.77 MB;
```

error which complains I surpass the file size allowed by GitHub.

The file it is complaining about is no longer in my version control as I deleted it for that exact reason of it being too big.

So when I try to follow the Git Documentations suggestion of doing

```
git rm <path-to-large-file>
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'app/assets/images/title00.mp4' did not match any files
```

Any idea how I should proceed?

Comment: What is the output of your `git status`? I feel like the removal has been staged and you just have to `git commit`.

Comment: Note that even if `git rm` works, you still probably won't be able to push to GitHub. The too-large file will still be in the repository history that is uploaded, even if it's removed from the latest commit.

Comment: @JeremyBanks but how do I remove it from the repository history?

Comment: @sjagr On branch stripe_payment
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/stripe_payment' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Comment: @sjagr nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: and then it lists all my untracked files none of which are the large `.mp4`

Comment: @Thalatta Depending on what you've done, it can be tricky. I can't give general instructions, but perhaps http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History could help.

Comment: Ah, you have the `mp4` in one of those earlier commits. You'll have to squash the commits together. Pretty much what @JeremyBanks is saying.

Comment: @sjagr so I rebase the last 5 commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Rewriting History Git docs](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#The-Nuclear-Option:-filter-branch):

> #### Removing a File from Every Commit
>
> This occurs fairly commonly. **Someone accidentally commits a huge binary file with a thoughtless `git add .`, and you want to remove it everywhere.** Perhaps you accidentally committed a file that contained a password, and you want to make your project open source. `filter-branch` is the tool you probably want to use to scrub your entire history. To remove a file named `passwords.txt` from your entire history, you can use the `--tree-filter` option to `filter-branch`:

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f passwords.txt' HEAD
Rewrite 6b9b3cf04e7c5686a9cb838c3f36a8cb6a0fc2bd (21/21)
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
```

In your scenario, you will probably want to do:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f app/assets/images/title00.mp4' HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clean files from your repo history with the great [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) repo cleaner.
Basically, you can run the following steps

First.
   Install bfg cleaner. In MacOSX, with `brew install bfg`.

Second, clear your file from your history.

```
git clone --mirror git@github.com:your_github_user/your_github_repo.git
bfg --delete-files title00.mp4 your_github_repo.git
cd your_github_repo.git
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git push
```

Then you have to clear your non mirror repor (your development folder) and clone it again from github to avoid repush the big file.

```
git clone git@github.com:your_github_user/your_github_repo.git
```

Obviously, more information in BFG website.